# How to iterate over items in object/array, and build a nested JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, underscore.js

I'm working with some JSON data and I need to take data from one object, and build out a JSON object.

EDITED: The resulting JSON is being used with the D3.js charting library, hence the strange question (and apparent down-votes)

My data being returned from an API looks like this:

```
var data = [
    [
        {"id": 1, "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
        {"id": 2, "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
        {"id": 3, "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
        {"id": 4, "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
        {"id": 5, "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"},
        {"id": 6, "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}
    ]
];
```

and I need my JSON to have each object nested inside the previous like this:

```
{
    "name" : "1",
    "children" : [
    {
        "name" : "2",
        "children" : [
            {
                "name" : "3",
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "4",
                        "children" : [
                            {
                                "name" : "5",
                                "children" : [
                                    {
                                        "name" : "6",
                                        "children" : [ ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I've only stopped at 6 for demonstrative purposes - I'd need something that can work with N objects.
Currently I'm looping over the `data` object with `_.each`, but can't figure out how to do the nesting.

Any help would be great - Thanks!

Comment: I need to do this because I'm building a D3 Tree visualization which uses this type of JSON

Comment: If your tree is recursive so should your method.

Comment: The problem I see is that there isn't really an overly general solution to what you're asking. The data likely has some ID linking parent and child, not just `array[n+1]` is a child of `array[n]`. This makes recursively building the object a different function than just arbitrarily nesting N levels deep. If that's TRULY how the structure is, I'll put something up here.

Comment: @cdbajorin Yes that's how the source data looks, and how the JSON needs to be structured.

Comment: @Toxantron - The data is from an API out of my control and the JSON structure is needed for the D3 library.

Comment: @gatebasher_311 This was not meant as criticism but rather the solution proposol to your problem.

Comment: Please read up on what JSON is, and how it is different from plain old JS objects.

Comment: Did any answers solve your problem? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var data = [ [{ "id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 4, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 5, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 6, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }] ];

var r = (function rec(d, o, i) {
    if (i == -1) return o;
    var t = {};
    t.name = d[i].id;
    t.children = [];
    t.children.push(o);
    return rec(d, t, --i);
})(data[0], {}, data[0].length - 1);


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(r, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with. @isvforall was a little faster, but I like mine better. ;)

```js
var data = [ [{ "id": 1, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 2, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 3, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 4, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 5, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }, { "id": 6, "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3" }] ];

var result = (function buildTree(input, index) {
  if (index >= input.length)
    return [];

  return [
    {
      name: input[index].id,
      children: buildTree(input, index + 1)
    }
  ];
})(data[0], 0);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

**Edit:** Added code from @isvforall for demonstration. Our solutions both use recursion, we just build the tree differently.